# My object isn't fully Rendered, but in viewport is alright

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, particles

I come to you today with this issue.
I've just start blender course @blenderguru (I really enjoy it;)).
As you can see (in render) my icing is gone... but sprinkles are there. And when I check it in blender viewport everything is alright. I am just starting learning, so please be nice :)

*Rendered image (icing doesn't show up)*

[image]

Here's how it looks like in *Rendered Preview*

[image]

And here's an image of my particles settings

[image]

P.S.: If it can help [here's the blender file](https://we.tl/t-fLrliyH2W2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable *Show Emitter* option, in *Particles Settings*.

It's often useful to have the emitter hidden, but in this case it is also an important part of your object.

Enable it here:
*Properties Panel > Particle Settings > Render*

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I would never have found it.

Comment: @AGM Happy to help :). It took me a few moments. Great donut by the way, good luck with your other models.