# Object not seen in render blender 2.81

Tags: modeling, rendering

I'm doing a sort of donut for my first time in Blender. I'm at a point where my icing is seen from the different views except when I'm in the rendeder view. I tried a few things like enable camera in the ray visibility or some others but no one works. It really weird because the springles on top of it are shown but not the icing.
Can someone help me, I'm a beginner on it so I don't know how to fix it ?? Below there are the first image that is from the viewport shading and the second one is from the render. Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). You need to check *Show Emitter* in your particle settings. [Here is my full answer to a very similar question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161565/78972)

Comment: Hiii, thank youu, I was searching for so long, you're the best !!